# Disable all elements in a layout - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

In my **Android** app there is a requirement that a number of UI elements should be disabled until a button is clicked. Can I disable all the UI elements in a **layout** by referring the **layout** without disable them one by one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could disable all views recursively like this.
Just pass the layout as view to the method:

```
private void enableViews(View v, boolean enabled) {
    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
        for (int i = 0;i<vg.getChildCount();i++) {
            enableViews(vg.getChildAt(i), enabled);
        }
    } 
    v.setEnabled(enabled);
}
```

Just run `enableViews(view, false)` to disable, or `enableViews(view, true)` to enable again.

Comment: by this I can disable my view in an action. Can i enable my view on some listener by using setEnabled(true) instead of setEnabled(false) for an initially disabled view.

Comment: OK. I can programmaticaly change the colors and make the enable and disable more interactive. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use following attribute in your xml layout (as a example textView):

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

In button click event:

```
myText.setVisible(myText.VISIBLE)
```

You can either use them one by one or you can put all invisible content in a single layout and hide the layout. Then once you want to show them, just VISIBLE the layout, then all will display.

Comment: thanks.this works. but it make my layout invisible at the beginning and can have it back. Can i do something like disable my layout while it is visible.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought there would be an inbuilt way.

Comment: thanks for your view. I can make the disable more interactive by using colors. Thanks a lot.

Comment: yep. I'm new to Android and need help from from professionals.